# Set the font of the title of window independently

Tags: dearpygui

I want to set the font of the title of a window as `font1` and any other items as `font2`.

I know I can achieve this as follow:

```py
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

dpg.create_context()
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font(...) as font1: 
        ...
    with dpg.font(...) as font2: 
        ...
dpg.bind_font(font1)

...

with dpg.window(...) as window1: 
    item1 = dpg.draw_line(...)
    item2 = dpg.add_text(...)
    item3 = dpg.add_button(...)
    ...
    # set the font of all the items one by one
    dpg.bind_item_font(item1, font2)
    dpg.bind_item_font(item2, font2)
    dpg.bind_item_font(item3, font2)
    ...
    # OR something a little bit smarter
    items = dpg.get_item_children(window1)
    for id in items[1]: 
        dpg.bind_item_font(id, font2)
    for id in items[2]: 
        dpg.bind_item_font(id, font2)
...
```

But such codes seems really stupid. Is there any function in dpg that can get a tag referring to the "item" of the title of the window? so that I can use code like this:

```py
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

dpg.create_context()
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font(...) as font1: 
        ...
    with dpg.font(...) as font2: 
        ...
dpg.bind_font(font2)

...

with dpg.window(...) as window1: 
    title_id = ... # get the tag of the window title "item"
    dpg.bind_item_font(title_id, font1)
    # or something like dpg.set_title_font(font1)

    item1 = dpg.draw_line(...)
    item2 = dpg.add_text(...)
    item3 = dpg.add_button(...)
    ...
    # the font of the rest of items are set to font2 by default
...
```